# When opening a script from Unity, Visual Studio opens the wrong solution

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have multiple Unity projects on this PC, however this problem only affects one of them, the one which is connected to Plastic SCM named "My Daughter's Adventure". Please ignore the name :). If I try to open a c# script from Unity, it opens it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR2rn.png). However, the correct .sln file does indeed exist in the correct folder, shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7nlK.png).

If I try to open one of my "offline" projects, everything works fine. Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpPuu.png).

Now, I can open the .sln file manually and then open the script file from Unity. That brings back Intelisense and that little code dropdown menu, but this method has been kind of bipolar. Sometimes everything works fine, otherwise I get errors in Unity regarding the name of the script that doesn't correspond with anything and  it asks me fix "compile errors" even if there aren't any.

Do note that I tried everything, at least what I could find online in terms of fixing this, including the preference settings in Unity. I'm also kinda new to Unity and Visual Studio. It took me 3 hours just to identify the problem and made an account just for this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try: Preferences > External Tools > regenerate solution, And then: Assets > Open C# Project

Comment: If you are refering to "Regenerate project files", yes I have tried that. I don't have a "Regenerate solution" button. I did try to manually delete the solution which didn't work either.